# VBA Bloomberg API

Tags: excel, vba, bloomberg

I want to run a macro that brings me the following value `INTERVAL_PERCENT_CHANGE` from:

- The ticher of the fund concerned `S3.Range(Cells(3, 76), Cells(3, 77))`.
- Start and end dates `S3.Cells(i, 73).Value` and `S3.Cells(i, 74).Value`
- Currency `S3.Cells(2, 76).Value`

from the Bloomberg APIs. But I get a soft error message

> "invalid procedure call or argument".

I really tried everything but there is something that escapes me.
the underlined line is the following:

```
range(cells(4,76),cells(12,77)).value  msg.GetElement("securitydata").GetValue(0).GetElement("fieldData").GetElement("INTERVAL_PERCENT_CHANGE").Value
```

Thank you for all your answers and insights. below the code in full

```
Sub ref_data()
    Dim session As blpapicomLib2.session
    Set session = New session
    session.Start

    Dim Service As blpapicomLib2.Service
    session.OpenService ("//blp/refdata")
    Set Service = session.GetService("//blp/refdata")

    Dim Request As blpapicomLib2.Request
    Set Request = Service.CreateRequest("ReferenceDataRequest")

    Request.Append "securities", "S3.Range(Cells(3, 76), Cells(3, 77)).Value"
    Request.Append "fields", "INTERVAL_PERCENT_CHANGE"
    Dim overrides As Element
    Set overrides = Request.GetElement("overrides")
    Dim override As Element
    Set override = overrides.AppendElment

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 4 To 12    
        Dim override1 As Element
        Set override1 = overrides.AppendElment

        override1.SetElement "fieldId", "Start_Date_Override"
        override1.SetElement "value", "S3.Cells(i, 73).Value" 'Replace date with the cell reference eg Range("B10").Value

        Dim override2 As Element
        Set override2 = overrides.AppendElment

        override2.SetElement "fieldId", "End_Date_Override"
        override2.SetElement "value", "S3.Cells(i, 74).Value" 'Replace date with the cell reference eg Range("A10").Value

        Dim override3 As Element
        Set override3 = overrides.AppendElment

        override3.SetElement "fieldId", "CRNCY"
        override3.SetElement "value", "S3.Cells(2, 76).Value" 'Replace EUR with the cell reference eg Range("A10").Value

        session.SendRequest Request

        Dim blpevent As blpapicomLib2.Event
        Dim it As blpapicomLib2.MessageIterator
        Dim msg As blpapicomLib2.Message
        Dim finalResponse As Boolean

        Do While finalResponse = False
            Set blpevent = session.NextEvent
            Set it = blpevent.CreateMessageIterator

            Do While it.Next
                Set msg = it.Message
                If blpevent.EventType = RESPONSE Or blpevent.EventType = PARTIAL_RESPONSE Then
                    range(cells(4,76),cells(12,77)).value  msg.GetElement("securitydata").GetValue(0).GetElement("fieldData").GetElement("INTERVAL_PERCENT_CHANGE").Value 
                End If

                If blpevent.EventType = RESPONSE Then
                    finalResponse = True
               End If
            Loop
        Loop
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Never worked with `Bloomberg API` but are you missing an "=" sign before `  msg.GetElement`?

Comment: I tried to add it but I have the same error message

Comment: Next try fully qualifying your cell objects. For example `Sheets("Sheet1").range(Sheets("Sheet1").cells(4,76),Sheets("Sheet1").cells(12,77)).value` Change "Sheet1" to relevant sheet

Comment: Also is `msg.GetElement("securitydata").GetValue(0).GetElement("fieldData").GetElement("INTERVAL_PERCENT_CHANGE").Value` the correct way to do it? Unfortunately I cant understand that part

Comment: I'd suggest `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to help prevents unqualified references.

Comment: @ Siddharth Rout i  just modified my cells but i get the same message, i follow an example found on Bloomberg, they used this way  but it doesn't work on my own file

Comment: Have you added the "Bloomberg API COM 3.5 Type Library" to your VBA project's references?

Comment: @assylias yes, i added it